# Should we allow lyrics request and lyrics translation of a certain anime?

Tags: discussion, allowed-topics

Should we allow lyrics translation of a certain anime? For example, a user asked for the english translation of a particular anime theme song. Should we allow questions like that? It is answerable and not too vague for a topic. It can be useful to attract more audience since a lot searches for anime lyric and for its translation. It inclines on anime as well though it is much more involved in Japanese language. What do you think?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### No.

I've never had an anime song I couldn't Google lyrics for, and translation is *definitely* off-topic.

I would say it is on-topic to ask the *name* of a particular theme song from an anime. Some of these, particularly from less well-known anime, can be hard to find online. But from there, it is the OP's responsibility to find the lyrics themselves (*animelyrics.com* is a good resource).

Comment: Yes, of course. But aren't we targeting users to use our site instead of other sites?

Comment: @xjshiya Of course. But many, if not most, songs were made independent of the anime and are not directly linked to it. "What song was used in X anime" is an anime-related question; "What is X quality of an anime theme song" is not. (This would be akin to asking for translations of episode content.)

Comment: Yeah I see your point. But if there exist a case where the song is related to the anime and requires explanation, can it be allowed then?

Comment: @xjshiya If you have the lyrics and ask how they related to the anime in some way, I would see that as being on-topic.

Comment: It's better to be clear. Thanks a lot. :)